# Calling WebSphere Web Service from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, web-services, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, websphere

We would like to call a websphere web service from silverlight.

If I have understood it correctly:

- Silverlight only supports async web service calls
- Websphere does not support async calls

Is this correct?

Is it possible to call websphere web services from silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general answer to your first question: There is no need for a webservice server to support asynchronous calls. Because HTTP is stateless, the server handles one request in one thread.
Generally speaking, the client can choose whether to wait for the response (synchronous) or to let a new thread wait for the response and do other things meanwhile (asynchronous).

The decision of doing synchronous or asynchronous calls is therefore only part of the client.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible.

Silverlight is asynchronous only in that the HTTP Web Request (GET, POST) is not linked to the receipt of the the HTTP response. You send an HTTP Request which is one action and separately from the Request you receive and handle the HTTP Response, you don't send a request then wait on the same thread for a response.

On your web server it makes no difference how you receive the request and send the response, so it could be handled synchronously or asynchronously, the Silverlight app would be oblivious to that.

Saying that 'Silverlight only supports async web service calls' only means that it does not block the calling thread while waiting for a response. The request is sent on one thread, the response is received on another thread.